# Using spatial regression on interpolated surfaces?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-statistics, regression, autocorrelation

I have two raster surfaces where I want to test to see If any relationship (A depending on B) can be found and if so if that relationship is statisticaly significant.

What are key issues to consider and look out for?

How would you propose that I go forth?

Both surface A and B are interpolated surfaces which are indexed (internally, that is to say they do not share the same 'unit' or range, their distributions/histograms are however similar but not identical). The question I want to answer is if their geographical distribution correlates.

I'm especially concerned with the risk of having induced spatial autocorrelation. I already now that one of the raster datasets is spatially autocorrelated and suspect that the other would yield similar results since they both show quite clear geographical patterns.

Hence what should I be wary of when doing a regression analysis on two interpolated surfaces?

I'm also seeking good references and further reading in the subject.

I don't consider myself an expert at spatial statistics.

I got access to ArcMap with all relevant licenses/extensions. I'm not familiar with R nor with advanced scripting.